# Random.php goes to a random link?

Tags: php, random

Bascially, I'm trying to make a random.php page where if someone goes on it, it will redirect them to a specific link I want, and everytime they go on random.php a different link will come so for example..

```
$urls = array('http://gamingwebsite.com/xlnc', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xln8', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xln5', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xln4', 
'http://gamingwebsite.com/xlmv', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xlms', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xllz', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xllp', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xllj', 
'http://gamingwebsite.com/xlle', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xll9', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xll5', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xlks', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xlkl', 
'http://gamingwebsite.com/xlke', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xlk4', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xljv', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xlje', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xlj9', 
'http://gamingwebsite.com/xlj1', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjxu', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjxd', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjx4', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjwz', 
'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjw1', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjup', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjtz', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjtt', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjtn', 
'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjrh', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjrd', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xjr3', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xj1z', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/xizx', 
'http://gamingwebsite.com/xizf', ' http://gamingwebsite.com/x3jx', 'http://gamingwebsite.com/x3jp');
```

This is the stuff I done, how can I make it so everytime someone goes on random.php it will redirect them to one of those links??

Comment: So, you have an array? Side note, if all your links start with `http://gamingwebsite.com/` don't bother adding them to the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy.  Just use [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/shuffle) to shuffle the array, and then grab the first item from the top of the newly randomized array and set a new `Location` via [`header`](https://www.php.net/header):

```
shuffle($urls);
header('Location: ' . $urls[0]);
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, @JakeGould. [Docs for the lazy](http://uk1.php.net/shuffle)

Answer (score 3):

Multiple ways. A simple way is to use a combination of [**`rand()`**](https://www.php.net/rand) and [**`count()`**](https://www.php.net/count)

```
header('Location:'. $urls[rand(0, (count($urls)-1))]);
```

Or use [**`array_rand()`**](https://www.php.net/array_rand)

```
header('Location:'. $urls[array_rand($urls, 1)]);
```

Comment: It wouldn't... I'll add that to my answer now